# A Binary Hash that forms Part of an SQL Statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, security, hash

While converting passwords into binary hashes to be stored in the database, I notice that other than the usual gibberish, there are also some quotes, spaces and alphabets which by some stroke of coincidence may form part of a valid SQL statement.

Out of curiosity, I would like to know whether anyone has encountered any string which magically transforms into part of a valid SQL statement upon hashing, whether by MD5, SHA1, etc.

**Add note:** Though this question may be security related, it is more of a curiosity question, since I already know how to defend against an injection attack.

Answer (score 2):

You should **never** be adding data to your database with:

```
string hash = Hash(password);
string sql = "update users set passwordHash = '" + hash +
             "' WHERE userID = " + userID;
```

Its very dangerous. This type of scenario is also common for SQL injection attacks.
To do it safely and properly you should use parameters.

```
string hash = Hash(password);
string sql = "update users set passwordHash = @hash WHERE userID = @userID";
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, dbConn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@userID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = userID;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@hash", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = hash;
    cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be extraordinary if the binary bytes of a hash digest formed any legal SQL syntax.  It's far more likely that it would just create *invalid* syntax and your query would generate an error.

Every database API has functions to protect your query from unintentional bad syntax due to special characters in string literals.  You need to learn how to use them.  For example if you use PHP, use the MySQLi or PDO extension.  Prepare the query with parameter placeholders, and send your hash string as a query parameter.

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

If you use any other language, similar functions exist.

---

Re comments:

I prefer to use query parameters instead of escaping, because it works for any data type, it doesn't suffer from character-encoding bugs, and it's easier to code.

There are cases where neither escaping nor query parameters work.  Table names, column names, lists of values for an IN() predicate, SQL keywords, expressions.  In my presentation [SQL Injection Myths and Fallacies](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-injection-myths-and-fallacies), I cover a method I use called "Whitelist Maps" that helps to cover the extraordinary cases like these.

I also cover SQL injection in my book [SQL Antipatterns Volume 1: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming](https://pragprog.com/titles/bksap1/sql-antipatterns-volume-1/).

Comment: Yes, `PDO` and `mysqli_real_escape_string` would be sufficient to stop any injection attacks. I am more curious about the extraordinary.

Comment: Please note that `mysqli_real_escape_string()` was not among Bill's suggestions and there's a good reason: it's the oldest and most annoying way to inject parameters from PHP.

Comment: @ Álvaro G. Vicario: what's so bad about `mysqli_real_escape_string`?